# Tensorflow Video Decoding on a Separate Thread in a Distributed System

Tags: multithreading, ffmpeg, tensorflow, video-streaming, distributed-computing

Having a distributed system, I need to enqueue frames on a CPU device, while processing the frames, that is, training the network, has to be done on a GPU device. Could this be performed in parallel (simultaneously) in tensorflow?

Currently, tensorflow enables Audio coding through FFMPEG(contrib), are there any features for video encoding and decoding which is multi-threaded?

Again, the purpose is is to perform an enqueue operation in one thread on a CPU device and through another thread, dequeue the frames and feed them to the graph which lies on a GPU device.

Currently I need to process more than a 100 video with a minimum duration of 10 minutes each.

Comment: Are you interested in treating the video as a time series, or just randomly selecting frames? If the latter, I would just decode them manually and treat this as an image model. Cross-device queue-like things are [not there yet](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5722) but [will be soon](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7679).

Comment: Okay, thank you Mr. @AllenLavoie

Comment: This is done if you want to check it out: https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_models